# Apache2 web server does not load most images: Internal server error

Tags: server, apache2, pdf, jpeg

I have reinstalled a school website previously on Ubuntu 14, now on Ubuntu 18 with LAMP software; now Apache2 web-server works fine except for images; it does load only a few images, and refuse all other with a 500 Internal server error; below are some cut by the Firefox Web Console; the most astonishing things are that the jpeg file is recognized as an html file (I've checked the jpeg file with text editor and first bytes are FFD8 which is Mime for jpeg, I read on the Apache2 magic file) and that it seems to have a cookie inside, with a web address that is mine and has nothing to do with the school website.

I checked many jpeg files refused by the webserver with Kaspersky and Commodo and both give : No menace found.

The same jpeg files are shown without problem on the same website mounted on my home web-server QNAP with LAMP also.

Any idea?

Thanks

Paolo Bonavoglia

PS The server seems to make confusion about MIME; it says a .js file is not a Javascript file while it is, and so for pdf,png and other formats all seen as html files

```
filename
    /eu_corridoio_240.jpeg
Indirizzo
    80.211.56.142:80
Stato500
Internal Server Error
VersioneHTTP/1.0
Trasferito185 B (dim. 0 B)

Connection
    close
Content-Length
    0
Content-Type
    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date
    Mon, 16 Nov 2020 15:00:37 GMT
Server
    Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Accept
    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language
    it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control
    max-age=0
Connection
    keep-alive
Cookie
    __utma=139233973.492933293.1555583658.1605527791.1605533463.5; __utmz=139233973.1605533463.5.3.utmcsr=uscite.bonavoglia.eu|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/preferiti_1618.html; __utmc=139233973; __utmb=139233973.7.10.1605533463
Host
    www6.liceofoscarini.it
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
    1
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0
```

**Edit 17 11 2020: SOLVED!!**  I had noticed that most images were treated as text files; from the error log, I noticed that every file was handled as a PhP file. Suddenly I understood the Apache2 conf file had something wrong and I found this row in the 000-default.conf file:

```
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

out of any context; so Apache2 handled every file as Php!!

Sorry, it was an oversight of mine!

I commented that line, restarted Apache and now it works fine!

Only a question left: why in spite of this error, Apache2 loaded a few jpeg images correctly??

Comment: 1) Are there any clues in the Apache error log? That's always the first place to look...
2) Is the website just plain HTML or based on some CMS like Joomla? In the second case, try to clean the server-side cache on the CMS.

Comment: Your PS may be wrong: the actual response is not a file, because no file was sent by the server. Instead the server sends a 500 error, which has the `html` mimetype. In any case, view the apache error log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` as @raj suggests.

Comment: 1) found little  meaningful for me; anyway here is a typical error: image co4 jpeg  -  [php7:emerg] [pid 31642] [client 151.49.42.200:57248] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'begin' (T_STRING) in /var/www/html/foscarini/foto/as13-14/co4.jpeg on line 19, referer: http://www6.liceofoscarini.it/orariodin/foto.phtml?Classe=546
 [php7:emerg] [pid 31547] [client 151.49.42.200:57251] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'begin' (T_STRING) in /var/www/html/foscarini/foto/as13-14/co4.jpeg on line 19, referer: http://www6.liceofoscarini.it/orariodin/foto.phtml?Classe=546

Comment: 2) I write html from scratch non CMS. Use Php like in this example; php asks mysql the jpeg for a foto of a class

Comment: File permissions on the images?

Comment: file permissions are always -rw-rw-r-- both for images loaded correctly, both for images refused

Comment: another cut from the error log for a static image (no PhP here): Mon Nov 16 17:56:06.595206 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 32166] [client 151.49.42.200:59382] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\x12' (ASCII=18) state=0 in /var/www/html/foscarini/europeo/eu_facciata_fronte.jpeg on line 323, referer: http://www6.liceofoscarini.it/europeo/
[ [php7:emerg] [pid 32166] [client 151.49.42.200:59382] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\x93\xedMM\xad\xce' (T_STRING) in /var/www/html/foscarini/europeo/eu_facciata_fronte.jpeg on line 323, referer: http://www6.liceofoscarini.it/europeo/

Comment: On this website, don't put the answer in the question and title it SOLVED. Write an answer instead.

Comment: I saw a similar question closed this way. Now I modified as required, I think there must be a visible way to let users know the question is solved and closed.

Answer (score 0):

17 11 2020: SOLVED!! I had noticed that most images were treated as text files; from the error log, I noticed that every file was handled as a PhP file. Suddenly I understood the Apache2 conf file had something wrong and I found this row in the 000-default.conf file:

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

out of any context; so Apache2 handled every file as Php!!

Sorry, it was an oversight of mine!

I commented that line, restarted Apache and now it works fine!

Only a question left: why in spite of this error, Apache2 loaded a few jpeg images correctly??
Tags